# Compiling a .Net Core Console App with Npgsql and CoreRT

Tags: .net-core, f#, npgsql, corert

I'm trying to compile a .net core console [application](https://github.com/OshoNot/coreRTissue/tree/master/fsharp) into native executable (linux-x64) on an ubuntu 18.04 docker container, using both coreRT and Npgsql. I'm currently using docker-compose to set up the DB and application containers.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    database:
        image: postgres:10
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=dbuser
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dbpassword
            - POSTGRES_DB=dbsample
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        tmpfs:
            - /var/lib/postgresql/data:rw,noexec,nosuid,size=400m
        volumes:
            - ./db-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

    prototype:
        build: .
        depends_on:
            - database
        links:
            - database:database
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        apt-transport-https \
        build-essential \
        clang \
        cmake \
        curl \
        git-core \
        gpg \
        libbz2-dev \
        libkrb5-dev \
        libncurses5-dev \
        libncursesw5-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        llvm \
        make \
        parallel \
        wget \
        zlib1g-dev

RUN wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.asc.gpg \
    && mv microsoft.asc.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ \
    && wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list \
    && mv prod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list \
    && chown root:root /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg \
    && chown root:root /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-2.2

ENV CppCompilerAndLinker=clang-6.0
ENV DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=true

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY ./HelloWorld.fsproj /home/app
COPY ./nuget.config /home/app
RUN dotnet restore

COPY ./ /home/app
RUN dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -c Release -v detailed -o outside

CMD ./outside/HelloWorld
```

When It gets to compile it (`dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -c Release -v detailed -o outside`), it enters infinite loop consuming all the memory avaiable for the container. Until it shows this error:

```
Task "Exec"
         "/root/.nuget/packages/runtime.linux-x64.microsoft.dotnet.ilcompiler/1.0.0-alpha-27919-02/tools/ilc" @"obj/Release/netcoreapp2.2/linux-x64/native/HelloWorld.ilc.rsp"
         Killed
   1:7>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.dotnet.ilcompiler/1.0.0-alpha-27919-02/build/Microsoft.NETCore.Native.targets(249,5): error MSB3073: The command ""/root/.nuget/packages/runtime.linux-x64.microsoft.dotnet.ilcompiler/1.0.0-alpha-27919-02/tools/ilc" @"obj/Release/netcoreapp2.2/linux-x64/native/HelloWorld.ilc.rsp"" exited with code 137. [/home/app/HelloWorld.fsproj]
       Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED.
   1:7>Done building target "IlcCompile" in project "HelloWorld.fsproj" -- FAILED.
   1:7>Done Building Project "/home/app/HelloWorld.fsproj" (Publish target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

It seems to be somehow related with the usage of generics and reflections in F#. I've looked in both [Npgsql](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql) and [coreRT](https://github.com/dotnet/corert) repos and couldn't find someone close to get them both working. Have anyone faced this problem? Or managed to use Npgsql and coreRT?

Comment: Have you verified that your problem is minimal? I.e. have you tried Npgsql without the F# dependency. I glanced at your repo and you don't seem to have reflection in it, so no obvious issues apart from Npgsql.

Comment: Yeah I did. it was able to compile with just adding Npgsql and don't even using it. Since I added just a connection string set and connection command, the compilation breaks. I didn't get to use reflection because I couldn't even been able to compile it.

Comment: You didn't read my comment. "I.e. have you tried Npgsql without the F# dependency?" To expand, have you tried C#+Npgsql+CoreRT?

Comment: Yes I did. The C# problem relies on the reflection, I was able to compile it as seen in [repo link](https://github.com/OshoNot/coreRTissue/tree/master/csharp). I got it the F# version to compile as well. I needed to bump up the docker memory to 6GB. Do you have any suggestion of guideline to build the reflection I.e building rd.xml?

Comment: OK two separate issues then. For the reflection one (reproducible from C#) you will have to ask/search on the CoreRT repo. I don't know the rd.xml syntax.

For the F# not compiling issue, your repro isn't actually minimal because it has a dependency on Npgsql.FSharp. I quickly glanced at that repo and it uses sprintf which is AOT-unfriendly. Just use Npgsql directly and test again.

Comment: It compiled OK. I got a System.TypeInitializationException. Cutted Off the Npgsql.fsharp and printf as well